# VBScript echo every 30 seconds

Tags: datetime, vbscript, datediff

The following code writes to the screen every iteration.  Based on my understanding of [the DateDiff documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp), it should only write every 30 seconds.  What did I do wrong?

```vbs
lasttime = Now
Do While Not data.eof
    'looping through database records
    if DateDiff(s,lasttime,Now) >= 30 Then
        lasttime = Now
        WScript.Echo "It's been 30 seconds..."
    End if
Loop
```

Comment: WScript.Sleep 30000 'wait for 30sec before moving to next line is far easier

Comment: No that will pause execution.  I definitely don't want that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if DateDiff(s,lasttime,Now) >= 30 Then
```

To this (note the quotes around "s")

```
if DateDiff("s",lasttime,Now) >= 30 Then
```

Comment: I can't decide if I love or hate it when it's something this simple.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: Have to wait 10 minutes :)